# can't pass variable as url parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameter-passing, es6-modules

I have some trouble with the code below:

```
function SidebarChat() {
 const [seed, setseed] = useState("")
useEffect(() => {
    setseed(Math.floor(Math.random() *  5000)); 
}, []);

return (
    <div className="sidebarChat">
        <Avatar src={'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg'}  />
    </div>
)
```

}

I can't pass `${seed}` in the URL.

When I pass, its showing an error in the URL line and the '${seed}' is considered as a hardcoded string.

Comment: You're using **quotes** for your string, you should be using **backticks** for template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Also be specific with your issue, rather than just saying it doesn't work. I assume what you meant was "instead of the variable appearing in the string, I'm literally getting "${seed}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using quotes instead of backquotes when expressing the src, so the ${seed} won't be interpreted as it should be

To fix the issue:

```
<Avatar src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg`}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yo need to remove string  `const [seed, setseed] = useState("")` to  `const [seed, setseed] = useState()`

Comment: no it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To add variable in string you have to put it in template literals as below:

`` `https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/${seed}.svg` ``

OR

you can also use variable in single quote as shown below:

`'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/' + seed + '.svg'`

To learn more about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)